# Android RecyclerView findChildViewUnder(x, y)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

in recyclerView i would like know the view item under my mousse when i'm **dragging** item.
I'm using  **findChildViewUnder(x, y)** but it return me bad result.

I have an horizontal recyclerView with 5 items (one,two,three,four,five) , for example  when i'm dragging item "Two" over item three,four,five findChildViewUnder(x, y) return me "TWO,ONE" and after ONE,ONE,ONE ....
I think Two is correct, because when i'm starting i'm over the two item but after it's wrong. I'm listenning onDrag

````
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        View viewSource = (View) event.getLocalState();
        int srcItemPosition = (int)viewSource.getTag();
        int viewId = v.getId();
        RecyclerView target;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        target = (RecyclerView) v.getRootView().findViewById(rvSource);
        RecyclerListAdapter recyclerListAdapter = (RecyclerListAdapter) target.getAdapter();
        View viewUnerDrag = target.findChildViewUnder(x, y);```
    I watched lot of posts , but any solution 
    Thanks for help 
    [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qto7c.jpg
````